# Angular PWA error fetching manifest on ngsw-cache-bust

Tags: node.js, angular, express, progressive-web-apps

I know there are many question about this already, but I didn't found a working answer to me.
I created a simple web application using angular and nodejs/express and everything works fine.
I added the service worker in order to make it available as PWA with the help of the *chrome lighthouse*

I fixed almost all the errors, but I always have this error where I can't fetch the manifest:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Manifest fetch failed! (status: 404)
>       at Driver. (ngsw-worker.js:2414)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at fulfilled (ngsw-worker.js:174)

This is the request which returns 404:

> http://localhost:8080/ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.4621319026872752

The only thing I did was

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

This is my project structure:
[image: Project structure]

[image: Backend]

[image: Frontend]

Thank you in advance